# SPARQL query of Person using EasyRdf on DBpedia

Tags: php, sparql, rdf, dbpedia, easyrdf

I want to get all information about a Person from the DBpedia SPARQL API.
First problem is, the request took too long time.
Second, I don't get back any information about the person I looked for.
I don't know what I am doing wrong?

My Code:

```
require_once "EasyRdf.php";
require_once "html_tag_helpers.php";
// Setup some additional prefixes for DBpedia
EasyRdf_Namespace::set('category', 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:');
EasyRdf_Namespace::set('dbpedia', 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/');
EasyRdf_Namespace::set('dbo', 'http://dbpedia.org/ontology/');
EasyRdf_Namespace::set('dbp', 'http://dbpedia.org/property/');
$sparql = new EasyRdf_Sparql_Client('http://dbpedia.org/sparql');
$result = $sparql->query(
    'SELECT *
        WHERE {
          ?person foaf:name ?name.
          ?person foaf:name ?name.
          FILTER(regex(?person,"John Lennon"))
        }
    '
);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

My Result:

```
EasyRdf_Sparql_Result Object
(
    [type:EasyRdf_Sparql_Result:private] => bindings
    [boolean:EasyRdf_Sparql_Result:private] => 
    [ordered:EasyRdf_Sparql_Result:private] => 
    [distinct:EasyRdf_Sparql_Result:private] => 
    [fields:EasyRdf_Sparql_Result:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => person
            [1] => name
        )

    [storage:ArrayIterator:private] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to get results with something like:

```
regex(?person,"John Lennon"
```

since the value of **?person** is a URI, not a string, and URIs don't contain spaces.  Instead, you could query for individuals with the actual name (don't forget the language tag), as in:

```
select * where {
  ?resource foaf:name "John Lennon"@en
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20*%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fresource%20foaf%3Aname%20%22John%20Lennon%22%40en%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

> *I want to get all information*

If you want to get all the property values about a person, you could extend the query with something like:

```
select ?subject ?property ?object { 
  ?resource foaf:name "John Lennon"@en ;
            ?property ?object .
}
```

Of course, that will only retrieve data where the person is the *subject* of the triples, but you might also care about things where the person is the *object* of a triple too, in  which case you might go for:

```
describe ?person where {
  ?person foaf:name "John Lennon"@en
}
```

[SPARQL results (N-Triples)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=describe%20%3Fperson%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20foaf%3Aname%20%22John%20Lennon%22%40en%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fplain&timeout=30000&debug=on)

The results of **describe** queries are implementation dependent, but it's pretty common to get all the triples of which the resource is the subject or object.

Comment: Thank you, but if I try the third query, I get an error back: `Fatal error: Class 'EasyRdf_Parser_JsonLd' not found in /var/www/EasyRdf/Format.php on line 461 `

Comment: @R2D2 Do you get an error back, or just a different type of response?  DESCRIBE queries return graphs, not a list of variable bindings.  E.g., if you run that query at the [DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql), the default is to give you a .ttl file back.  If you request N-Triples back, you get what I just added a link to in the answer.

Comment: I want to search for a name and show the most important information about the person or the object on the webpage. But if I get N-Triples back it makes me not right i think. Or can I convert the N-Triples File to a array?

Comment: If you do something like `select ?property ?object where { ?subject ?property ?object }`, you're getting property/object pairs, and those are the just the property and object from a triple.  If you do `describe ...`, then you get a model back, i.e., a set of triples.  You can extract the property/object pairs from that just as easily.  But you haven't said anything about how you define "the most important information".

Comment: With "most important" i mean information like birthdate,birthplace,childrens,songs and similar people. Like google gives me if I search after John lennon.

Comment: @R2D2 Sure, but what programmatic specification do you have that would let you identify a "most important" property vs. a "less important" property.  If you can't specify it, you can't code it.

Comment: First I want to check if its a object or a human or a country o.e... And create some arrays where I have the important information propertys like `$country = array("population", "size"...)`. Well if its a country I check if an array with most important country propertys exists, if not cancel but if those array exists it should take the information and print it.

Comment: @R2D2  So, it sounds like you'll have a list of classes, and for each class a list of properties, and you want to retrieve those properties for each instance of those classes.  You can do that in SPARQL.

Comment: yes I want do it in steps: 1. Search for keyword Like "John Lennon" and check what it is (Human, Musician, Politician, Country...). 2. Check if a array exists and send a query using SPARQL which return the information I want to have (array). 3. Convert the N-Triples to a array and print it out. But I don't know which query I have to use (cause describe returns the error) and how do I convert the N-Triples into an array?