# How to fetch SPARQL query result using EasyRdf

Tags: php, sparql, semantic-web, fuseki, easyrdf

Using EasyRdf, I want to fetch query result. I used below code in codeigniter:

```
$this->load->library('rdf');
EasyRdf_Namespace::set('rdf', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns');
EasyRdf_Namespace::set('srt', 'http://persuratan-semweb.dev/ontologies/surat.owl');
$sparql = new EasyRdf_Sparql_Client('http://localhost:3030/surat_single/sparql');

$query = "SELECT * WHERE { "
            . "?surat rdf:type srt:Surat . "
            . "?surat srt:sifat_surat ?sifat_surat . "
            . "?surat srt:nomor_surat ?nomor_surat . }";
$result = $sparql->query($query);

echo "jumlah data: " . $result->numRows() . "<br>";
echo "<br>";

foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row->sifat_surat . " " .$row->sifat_surat . " " . $row->nomor_surat ."<br>";
}

print_r($result);
```

The output I got are:

```
jumlah data: 0

EasyRdf_Sparql_Result Object ( 
    [type:EasyRdf_Sparql_Result:private] => bindings
    [boolean:EasyRdf_Sparql_Result:private] =>
    [ordered:EasyRdf_Sparql_Result:private] =>
    [distinct:EasyRdf_Sparql_Result:private] =>
    [fields:EasyRdf_Sparql_Result:private] => Array ( 
        [0] => surat
        [1] => sifat_surat 
        [2] => nomor_surat 
    ) 
    [storage:ArrayIterator:private] => Array ( )
)
```

I also try Joshua's solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988928/sparql-query-of-person-using-easyrdf-on-dbpedia/29991983#29991983), but got similar output. I also try my query in Fuseki endpoint (I'm using Fuseki triplestore) and got this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejJ5M.png). I'm completely beginer in semantic web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether it's the answer or not, but these namespaces don't look right to me:

```
EasyRdf_Namespace::set('rdf', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns');
EasyRdf_Namespace::set('srt', 'http://persuratan-semweb.dev/ontologies/surat.owl');
```

The **rdf** namespace should have a # at the end, and you should probably have one for your OWL file, too:

```
EasyRdf_Namespace::set('rdf', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#');
EasyRdf_Namespace::set('srt', 'http://persuratan-semweb.dev/ontologies/surat.owl#');
```

But that said, there's no reason you can't try a *simpler* query first.  Why not just run

```sql
SELECT ?s ?p ?o { ?s ?p ?o }
```

to be sure that you can get results, and what the data is.